# The famous Portia's casket problem

Tags: logic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Gold casket: the portrait isn't in the silver casket.
Silver: the portrait isn't in this casket.
Lead: the portrait is in this casket.

At least one of the statements was true and at least one of them was false.
Which casket contains the portrait.

If you say any one of the three statements is true, you will end up with all of them being true.

Comment: I found this in a book. And no answer is provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is in lead, all the statements are true.  If it is in silver, they are all false.  If it is in gold, gold and silver are true, lead is false.  Only gold is acceptable

Comment: Now wow, how easy is this

Comment: Ross, did you heard of the preachers problem. A island of married couples. If any wife cheat on their husband, everyone else would know. Note that no one has kids. But this time, a wife cheated, but her husband does not know this... I forgot the rest.

Comment: @user139024:  yes, it is more often the [blue eyes puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_knowledge_(logic))  If you search for blue eyes puzzle you will find many links.  That one is *much* more subtle.  As the new information (if there is more than one cheater) is something "everybody knows" it is hard to explain how it changes anything.